# Extending an interface to another interface

Tags: java, interface

Let's say I have 2 interfaces here, `Moveable` and `Walkable` (sorry for the bad example, but please if you have a better one kindly post it)

```
interface Runnable{
    void run();
}

interface Walkable extends Runnable {
    void walk();
}

public class Human implements Walkable {

}
```

And the interface `Walkable` is a subclass of `Runnable`, when the `Human` class implements the `Walkable` interface should the `Human` class provide implementations for `void walk()` from the interface `Walkable` and `void run()` from the interface `Runnable`? does the interface `Walkable` inherit the abstract method `run()` from the interface `Runnable`?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Yes! it does inherit the method from the parent interface. Your class needs to implement both methods other wise the compiler will complain.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo if I could I wouldn't have posted it here. Apparently there's no java compiler in this unit.

Comment: Yes, the class implementing the interface with inheritance of another interface needs to implement all methods within the two interfaces. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your Human class will need to implement both the walk() and run() methods.

Comment: @Puce what are the criterias or when should I favor interfaces over abstract classes?

Comment: Usually you use abstract classes if you have partial implementations or have to extend a specific base class. Also consider to implement partial implementations (abstract classes) for your interfaces, if there is a good default implementation for some of the methods. Generally, I recommend to prefer interfaces over abstract classes without interfaces where possible. It makes the contract clearer, IMHO.

Comment: E.g. in this case you could implement the run-method in Human, but not the walk-method (or the other way around). Or even none of them. But then you have to declare Human as abstract and sub-classes will have to provide the missing implementations or have to be declared as abstract themselves.

Answer (score 2):

`should the human class provide implementations for void walk from the interface walkable and void run() from the interface runnable?`

Yes , when your  `Walkable`  interface extends `Runnable` it also inherits `run` method means now if `Human` class is implementing `Walkable` interface it has to implement both the methods otherwise it should be `abstract`.

Implementing an `Interface` is a contract where Implementing class has to implement all the methods declared in Interface.

`does the interface Walkable inherit the abstract method run() from the interface Runnable?`

Yes, It is the OOPS `Inheritance` concept.

Answer (score 1):

> when the Human class implements the Walkable interface should the human class provide implementations for void walk from the interface walkable and void run() from the interface runnable?

Yes. You could have discovered this very easily by trying to compile the code. The compiler would complain because there are no implementstions of the `run` and `walk` methods in class `Human`.

> does the interface walkable inherits the abstract method run() from the interface runnable?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

A Walkable is a Runnable, hence it must have the run() function defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your human should `walk` AND `run`.

Which would mean to invert the thing no? If you run you can certainly walk.But someone injured could walk without running ...

Answer (score 0):

yes, an interface can extend multiple interfaces and the implementing class should implement all the methods inherited by the implementing interface.

So yes to your question, you must implement both methods

Answer (score 0):

Human class needs to implement both methods, otherwise - you must declare it abstract. And yes, Walkable interface inherits the method run() from Runnable interface.

You can learn more about interfaces and inheritance [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).